Who is not cut out for chess?
What if someone studies for a few years and only gets a triple digit rating of 400 or 800?
They will probably remain a wood pusher for the rest of their lives, so playing is a waste of time.
For anyone, staying at an extremely low skill level is boring and leads to constant dissatisfaction...

Welcome on Chess.SE ! Can you precise exactly what your question is ? Now it seems a bit unclear or an attempt to open a discussion about the interest of playing at low skill, the kind of open debate that Stack Exchange isn't made for... (FWIW, I know many low-skilled players who do genuinely love the game and enjoyin themselves playing chess). Thanks !

"For anyone, staying at an extremely low skill level is boring and leads to constant dissatisfaction..."  Citation Needed  Many people are objectively poor tennis players but love tennis. Same for many other sports, video games, and board games.  I find this statement you make to be possibly true for you, but false as stated for others.


Who is not cut out for chess?

The answer is very simple - anyone who doesn't enjoy playing chess for its own sake.
Note that your claims about playing at a low level and so being dissatisfied may apply to you personally but do not apply to everyone. The enjoyment comes first and the improvement in level comes later. Somebody who enjoys the game of chess and perseveres will improve, although not necessarily to a high level. Many of us get great pleasure from playing against similar levels players even though we will never be masters of any description.

If you feel that chess is boring and that playing is a waste of time "pushing wood" around on a board, perhaps you are not cut out for chess regardless of your rating.  If it interests you regardless of your skill level, then perhaps the opposite is true.
Even if your skill does not improve and you find playing a waste of time, you may find other aspects of chess to be interesting.  Some might enjoy watching play-throughs of games that others have played, especially those at a high level, even if they cannot come up with brilliant moves themselves. One might find that the challenge of solving a chess puzzle holds their attention and even if they give up on solving it, may find the reveal to be enlightening or appreciate exposure to it.
You might also consider the environment in which chess is played.  Do you find chess more interesting when it is played over the board with another person, electronically or online, or when played against the computer where you can adjust the difficulty level so that it is challenging enough to not be easy but not hard enough to become discouraged?  Do you like to think deeply about your next move, or play rapidly?   Is it more interesting to play competitively or just for fun?  Would you prefer to play at a club, at home, or some other setting?
Once you have answered some of these questions you may start to get a better idea if chess is right for you.
